# Where do those profile images come from?

Tags: sync

I looked into the contacts of my Nexus 10 with Android 4.4.2 and noticed that some of my contacts have profile images. It looks like this:

http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2014-01-24/Screenshot_2014-01-24-17-49-27.png

However, I do not know this image, nor did I put it there myself. Where does that come from? I checked the settings and saw that my Google Account has full synchronisation enabled. Do those come from there?

I know that I deactivated some Google services but they kept coming back with Android updates, so I enabled them all again (why bother, if it does not work?). Did that activate synchronisation? I feel pretty angry since the tablet essentially leaked all my private data to Google now …

Comment: It might probably come via Google+. And yes, if you're not very careful and check all settings, many details get "leaked", as account sync (contacts, calendar, etc.) is turned on by default.

Comment: I just logged into the Google account on a desktop browser. I can see data there that I never wanted to see there (Contacts, search history). So, kick out the Google account and have no access to new apps?

Comment: And the images are on Google+, so I assume the tablet took them from there.